# Find and copy to multiple sub directories

Tags: unix, terminal, find

Hi I am trying to do a find and copy to multiple preferences folders within user files just a plist but coming up on an error. I am hopping someone can help point it out for me or help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
find . -type d -name 'Preferences' -maxdepth 3 -exec cp -r {} /Users/ladmin/Desktop/source.plist *Library/Preferences \;
```

Running just this

```
find . -type d -name 'Preferences' -maxdepth 3
```

prints out what I am trying to copy into `username/Library/Preferences`

Then I want to copy the plist to the preferences folder of every user.

I hope this isn't too complicated for people to read.

Thanks Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure why that should cause an error, though it does have several issues.

- `find` is recursive and `cp -r` is recursive, and they are both traversing the same tree. You can add the `-prune` test to `find` to stop it from descending found directories
- Not sure if this effects anything here, but `find` generally likes `options` (i.e. `-maxdepth`) to come first.
- `*Library/Preferences` if this expands to multiple paths all but one of them will get copied into the last one.

But, I think the main issue is that you are trying to copy a bunch of directories named `Preferences` into a single directory, so only one of them will actually get copied, and the rest will get overridden out.

```
find -maxdepth 3 -type d -name 'Preferences' -prune -exec echo cp -ivr {} /Users/ladmin/Desktop/source.plist username/Library/Preferences +
```

This fixes all of the first issues, but it's not clear from the question what should happen when a directory with that name already exists. The `-iv` will prompt you if you want to override when conflicts occur and add some verbosity. The `+` speeds up execution of `find` for commands that can take multiple file/dir names (like `cp`).